# How to append two argument items into a stack (Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, stack, binary-tree

So I'm currently practicing DFS & BFS approaches to binary trees and I am confused on how multiple arguments are being passed into the `.append` statements below. I know that `.append` can only take one argument and that when the the arguments are encapsulated in parenthesis they are treated as so, but what does it mean when you encapsulate them?

```
class Solution:
    def maxDepth(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: int
        """ 
        stack = []
        if root is not None:
            stack.append((1, root)) # <---- Here

        depth = 0
        while stack != []:
            current_depth, root = stack.pop()
            if root is not None:
                depth = max(depth, current_depth)
                stack.append((current_depth + 1, root.left))  # <---- Here
                stack.append((current_depth + 1, root.right))  # <---- Here

        return depth
```

To reiterate, what does `.append((arg1, arg2))` mean? How are those `args` treated and what logic is behind it?

Comment: `(1, root)` creates a tuple here... That's about it really... see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple

Comment: You are passing a tuple as argument to `.append()`.

Comment: The key insight is the tuple mimics arguments to functions on the call stack. The list is being treated as a FIFO, just like the call stack you'd use if you wrote this recursively. You can think of each element in the list as a stack frame, or "state"/"node" in the search space.

Comment: As to what the logic is behind it.... it appears they're getting unpacked by doing `current_depth, root = stack.pop())`... for use...

Comment: @timgeb That seems like a poor dupe target... In this question the tuple is not used to extend the list, quite the opposite, it's used as a single argument.

Comment: @Norrius well the dupe exactly explains what appending of an iterable does in the accepted answer.